# Comment poser une question <verbe> <sujet> avec « ça » ?

Tags: pronoms, questions, inversion

Je peux ? → Puis-je ?
On va ? → Va-t-on ?

Y a-t-il une manière de poser une question en utilisant « ça ».

Que deviendrait « ça va ? » avec la transformation utilisée ci-dessus ?

Comment: Ha bhé oui ! ***va-ce ?*** Mhé bon... pour être très correct... ce n'est pas trop usité. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'inversion ne s'effectue jamais en conservant le pronom *ça* comme sujet. L'une des raisons est probablement la différence de registre entre l'inversion qui est caractéristique de la langue soutenue alors que *ça* est du domaine du langage familier.

D'une manière générale, les pronoms démonstratifs ne sont pas maintenus lors d'une inversion. Les pronoms démonstratifs non neutres, comme celle[-ci], celui[-là], ceux[-ci], etc sont remplacés par les pronoms personnels correspondants :

> Celle-ci vient.
>
> [Celle-ci] Vient-elle ?
>
> Ceux-là se sont perdus.
>
> [Ceux-là] Se sont-ils perdus ?

Les pronoms démonstratifs neutres *ça* et *cela* n'ont pas de correspondants personnels et sont inutilisés dans des inversions.

Seul le pronom démonstratif neutre *ce* apparaît parfois dans des inversions.

Quand *ça* est interchangeable avec *ce*, l'inversion est envisageable :

> Ça serait lui. (équivalent à *Ce serait lui.*)

donne

> Serait-ce lui ? (jamais: *<s>Serait-ça</s> lui* !)

Mais le plus souvent cette inversion, possible il y a quelques siècles, est aujourd'hui une fantaisie humoristique :

> Ça sera lui. (*Ce sera lui.*)
>
> Sera-ce lui ?

Quand *ça* est interchangeable avec *cela*, l'inversion n'est jamais effectuée :

> Ça marche.
>
> <s>Marche-ça</s> ?
>
> <s>Marche-cela</s> ?

Dans l'écrasante majorité des cas, la forme interrogative est simplement réalisée soit en débutant la question par *est-ce que...* :

> Est-ce que ça sera lui ?
>
> Est-ce que ça marche ?
>
> Est-ce que ça va ?

soit, à l'oral, simplement par l'intonation :

> Ça sera lui ?
>
> Ça marche ?
>
> Ça va ?

Comment: ...quand la forme interrogative et son inversion sont encore utilisées, ce qui tend à diminuer. "Est-ce que ça marche ?" sera de nos jours très souvent remplacé par "Ça marche ?"

Comment: hmmm, je me demande s'il y a un lien avec le fait que "ca" ne soit pas un pronom. Par exemple, "Je suis la" peut se poser "Suis-je la ?" ; maintenant "Quelqu'un est la." ne se posera pas "Est quelqu'un la ?"

Comment: @LaurentS.Oui,c'est vrai. L'absence d'inversion est la forme la plus courante à l'oral.

Comment: _Pronom_ demonstratif, je suppose.

Answer (score 4):

On peut inverser le sujet et le verbe, mais il faut alors remplacer « ça » par « cela » : « Cela va-t-il ? »

Comment: Est-ce que "Cela" est toujours le sujet dans la phrase que vous proposez ? Si oui, quand est-il de "il" ?

Comment: Ce serait bien de noter que la phrase "cela va-t-il ?" n'a rien d'idiomatique.